# Compare two arraylists with contains instances of classes

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to compare two arraylists containing the instances of two separate classes with one another.

Eg:
1st list: HKY SGP 15:00 3 20:20 700

2nd list: 1 HKY SGP 8:00

so if the 1st list contains the words HKY and SGP, then the value 700 needs to be returned.
Both of these are compared in a separate class called cost. I pass the arraylists to this cost class using the main method. This cost class then proceeds onto compare the arraylists.

What i have tried: 
I googled the problem and tried using some solutions they provided. 
I have tried using contains or equal. It gives me an incorrect value.

Then i tried using the get method from both the classes to compare. It does not give the desired output too.

I think i am comparing both these objects incorrectly, not sure on how to compare. Can someone shed some light on how to compare these objects in the arraylist?

Thank you!

Code in main:

```
    ArrayList<planes> air = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<questions> q = new ArrayList(); // same as below for questions

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    num = sc.nextInt();


    for (int i=0; i<num; i++){  
       planes p = new planes();

       p.setfrom(sc.next());
       p.setTo(sc.next());
       p.setdT(sc.next());
       p.setaD(sc.next());
       p.setaT(sc.next());
       p.setCt(sc.next());
       air.add(p);


    }
```

Comment: can you post some of your code so we can have a look

Comment: How about using object orientation, that is instead of using lists of different Strings, create a class which holds those strings and can compare itself with another instance of this class?

Comment: if (list1.contains("HGY") && list1.contains("SGP") && list2.contains("HGY") && list2.contains("SGP")) { return 700; }

Comment: @RyanHurling Posted a small portion of my code, the rest are just getters and setters

Comment: @SpongeBobFan I am looking to compare both the lists with one another, so  if list 1 contains the values in list 2, then 700 will be outputted

Comment: @Phantom Please see my answer below (for a different question which you deleted)

Answer (score 3):

Write a custom `Comparator<T>` to do what you need.

Maybe a regex for both would do it:

```
// two Strings both contain "foo"
return x.matches("[foo]") && y.matches("[foo]");
```

If regex can't do it, implement your own Knuth-Morris-Pratt matcher:

http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960227.html

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a `Comparator<T>`. So implementing interface will have to override its `compare(T arg0, T arg1)` method. At **`T`** you can put any type to compare with. Like ArrayList<>(), Class, String etc. And to check whether string contains HKY SGP; if these are always adjacent then you can directly do like:

```
public int compare(String list1, String list2) {

    return list1.contains("HKY SGP") && list2.contains("HKY SGP") ? 700 : 0;
}
```

this will return 700 if both strings contains "HKY SGP" else 0.

If "SGP" is not always after "HKY" then just check for each of them. Something like:

```
return list1.contains("HKY") && list1.contains("SGP") && list2.contains("HKY") && list2.contains("SGP") ? 700 : 0;
```

Comment: Thank you :) But, I am looking to compare both the lists, so if list 1 contains the values in list 2, then 700 will be outputted.

Comment: so you are saying that you're comparing "**air**" with "**q**" ? But in fact you've to compare some property of **planes** (like string / getFrom()) with some property of **questions** (like string) then return 700 right ? Correct me if I'm wrong.

For that from the lists you can take a specific position and class at that position, and pass them to compare with some of it's property. If I'm correct then let me know so that we can discuss how to compare two diff classes. Also let me know what variables are in **questions** class.

Comment: Yup, you are right. Currently, i have done this in the cost method, to check if i the value is passed properly,                                   for(int i=0; i<a.size() ; i++){
         s = q.get(i).getFC();
        
        }                                                                   But, it keeps on giving this error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

Comment: this is mainly because your list **`air`** is having diff size than list **`q`**. Suppose **`air.size()`** is **3** and **`q.size()`** is **1**. Then inside that for loop for iterations, **`q.get(0)`** will work as size is **1**, but for **`q.get(1 or 2)`** will crash as though **`air.size()`** is **3** **`q`** is holding only single class. That's why you're getting IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: welcome, accept the answer if this is what you searching for.